# How to auto start virtual machine in VMware for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vmware-workstation

Currently installed `VMware` Workstation on `Ubuntu 14.04` server and in that the `VMware` Workstation version is 11.0.0 build 2305 329 is installed now, our question is as follow

Currently we have created 4 different virtual machine inside the workstation, now we want to `autostart` those machine when the host machine gets started in a different order. So what is the procedure we should do to get things done?

We've already searched for solutions over the Internet but couldn't find much about it or rather we are not searching in a proper manner. Can anybody help us in this regard and earliest please.

We thank you for your time and your reply in advance so what's this post

Have a good day

Comment: You can use `cron`job  with `@reboot`

Comment: Can I know what to write for this in the cronjob?